# Cannot pushing toast to WP8 from Azure mobile services

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, windows-phone-8

I got some problem to display the Toast notification by following the tutorial

Here the Azure mobile service server script:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
request.execute({
    success: function () {
        // Write to the response and then send the notification in the background
        request.respond();
        push.mpns.sendToast(item.channel, {
           text1:"Sent from cloud!"
       }, {
            success: function (pushResponse) {
                console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And this is the coding i put in App.xaml.cs:

```
//push notification
    public static HttpNotificationChannel CurrentChannel { get; private set; }


    private void AcquirePushChannel()
    {
        CurrentChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("MyPushChannel");


        if (CurrentChannel == null)
        {
            CurrentChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyPushChannel");
            CurrentChannel.Open();
            //CurrentChannel.BindToShellTile();
            CurrentChannel.BindToShellToast();
        }
    }

private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        AcquirePushChannel();
    }
```

But the toast still not coming out(the fliptile is working well).

Any modification needed to make the toast working ?

EDIT:
error when opening channel:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Open failed because the channel was already open.  You can find an open channel by calling the Find method.
  Source=Microsoft.Phone
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Phone.Notification.SafeNativeMethods.ThrowExceptionFromHResult(Int32 hr, Exception defaultException, NotificationType type)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Notification.HttpNotificationChannel.Open()
       at UtemFtmkDB.App.AcquirePushChannel()
       at UtemFtmkDB.App.Application_Launching(Object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.FireLaunching()
       at Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.ITask.Launching.Invoke()
       at Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.Task.FireOnLaunching()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the application is running on the foreground when the toast notification is received, it won't show the toast in the UI; instead, you can receive it by subscribing to the [ShellToastNotificationReceived event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.notification.httpnotificationchannel.shelltoastnotificationreceived%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). If you do so, you'll receive the notification on the event handler.

*Edit after update in the question*: To prevent the `InvalidOperationException` while calling `Open`, you can use the code below:

```cs
private void AcquirePushChannel()
{
    CurrentChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("MyPushChannel");

    if (CurrentChannel == null)
    {
        CurrentChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyPushChannel");
    }

    if (CurrentChannel.ConnectionStatus == ChannelConnectionStatus.Disconnected)
    {
        CurrentChannel.Open();
    }

    if (!CurrentChannel.IsShellToastBound)
    {
        CurrentChannel.BindToShellToast();
    }
}
```

Comment: CurrentChannel.Open(); 
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Unknown Module. but was not handled in user code

what error is this, yesterday dont have this

Comment: Is there any more information on the exception? Message, stack trace, etc?